# iOS UIWebView CSS animations 1080p

Tags: ios, uiwebview, css-animations

I am seeing performance issues running CSS animations on the new iPad and iPhone 4S with a UIWebView on a 1080p external display, the main screen contains no windows.

The [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) fade is choppy when the image is 1920x1080 and the external screen is running at 1080p. However, when running the external display at 720p the animation is smooth, same thing without the external screen in retina mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that 1080p has over 4 times the resolution to deal with than 720p, so it's expected that there would be lower performance. There probably isn't a single one-stop fixit for this problem, and you may consider just only supporting 720p in the end.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why movies play smoothly full frame 1080p at 30 fps on external devices. That's a far greater load on the GPU/CPU than flipping between static images with trivial short lived animations. The other thing it does not explain is why the animations, when running on the iPad3's screen at even higher resolution than 1080p work flawlessly (remember this is not video). They should be just as slow. Could there be a different and slower frame buffer for external displays? Or could the external frame buffer only support hardware acceleration for video playback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work, by adding the following CSS to the image elements:

-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);

It enables hardware acceleration for the element.